# 'list' object has no attribute 'items' in Python's BeautifulSoup renderContents

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, html-sanitizing

In an attempt to remove unwanted/unsafe tags and attributes from input, I am using the below code (almost entirely by http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1655/):

```
def html_filter(value, allowed_tags = 'p h1 h2 h3 div span a:href:title img:src:alt:title table:cellspacing:cellpadding th tr td:colspan:rowspan ol ul li br'):
    js_regex = re.compile(r'[\s]*(&#x.{1,7})?'.join(list('javascript')))
    allowed_tags = [tag.split(':') for tag in allowed_tags.split()]
    allowed_tags = dict((tag[0], tag[1:]) for tag in allowed_tags)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(value)
    for comment in soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
        comment.extract()
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name not in allowed_tags:
            tag.hidden = True
        else:
            tag.attrs = [(attr, js_regex.sub('', val)) for attr, val in tag.attrs.items() if attr in allowed_tags[tag.name]]
    return soup.renderContents().decode('utf8')
```

It works well for unwanted or whitelisted tags, attributes not whitelisted and even badly formatted html. However if any whitelisted attributes are present, it raises

```
'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

at the last line, which is not helping me much. `type(soup)` is `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` whether it raises an error or not, so I don't know what it's referring to.

```
Traceback:
[...]
File "C:\Users\Mark\Web\www\fnwidjango\src\base\functions\html_filter.py" in html_filter
  30.     return soup.renderContents().decode('utf8')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in renderContents
  1098.             indent_level=indentLevel, encoding=encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in encode_contents
  1089.         contents = self.decode_contents(indent_level, encoding, formatter)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode_contents
  1074.                                   formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode
  1021.             indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode_contents
  1074.                                   formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode
  1021.             indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode_contents
  1074.                                   formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode
  1021.             indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode_contents
  1074.                                   formatter))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py" in decode
  983.             for key, val in sorted(self.attrs.items()):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /"nieuws"/article/3-test/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Are you sure `tag.attrs` isn't supposed to be a dictionary?  (it started out as one and you changed it to a list)

Comment: I'm trying to remember why I changed that... So far nothing seems to have broken when I changed it back, maybe my brain malfunctioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
tag.attrs = [(attr, js_regex.sub('', val)) for attr, val in tag.attrs.items() if attr in allowed_tags[tag.name]]
```

with

```
tag.attrs = dict((attr, js_regex.sub('', val)) for attr, val in tag.attrs.items() if attr in allowed_tags[tag.name])
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `renderContents()` expects you to set `attrs` to a `dict` (which would have an `items` method), rather than the list of tuples you pass. Hence it throws `AttributeError` when it tries to access it.

To fix the error, you can use a dict comprehension in Python 3:

```
tag.attrs = {attr: js_regex.sub('', val)) for attr, val in tag.attrs.items() if attr in allowed_tags[tag.name]}
```

In Python 2, dict comprehensions aren't supported so you should pass an iterator to the `dict` constructor:

```
tag.attrs = dict((attr, js_regex.sub('', val)) for attr, val in tag.attrs.items() if attr in allowed_tags[tag.name]))
```